# Openerp javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, odoo

Is there a way to debug the javascript code from an openerp module? 
I am using Eclipse.
I tried Firebug, but the javascript code is already minified and is very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the ?debug in the url as following `http://127.0.0.1:8069/?debug`

and it's better if you use Crome activating the developer mode

regards,
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

Use chromium or chrome. User developer console to see logs